# Please help me understand beginner data

Tags: mining

I see the following "In Ethereum the performance is 71 MH/s (+-5%)." - What does that mean for a beginner who wants to learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would most likely be the HashRate of the gpu give or take 5 percent. It is hard to know without more information but since it looks like your question is about mining Ethereum, I think this is what you are asking about.

The HashRate of the gpu (your graphics card) is the hash rate at which your card performing the work works to solve the algorithm for each block. 71 MH/s is a decent hashrate for mining.